# Order articles by average article rating

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to be able to order my articles based on their rating which I solved using the following query:

```
return Article::where('private', 0)
    ->whereIn('movie_id', $movie)
    ->with(['user', 'movie', 'ratings'])
    ->withCount(['ratings as average' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(\DB::raw('coalesce(avg(value), 0)'));
    }])
    ->orderByDesc('average')
    ->paginate(10);
```

The problem is however if an article only has 1 or 2 ratings/votes and they are all positive ratings then the article will rank with other top articles that have many more ratings/votes which gives inaccurate results. How would I limit it only to articles with let's say more than 5 votes? Is there any other other better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ratings` is a relation hasMany, you can simply use :

```
return Article::where('private', 0)
         ->has('ratings', '>=', 5)
         ...
```

To only get articles with 5 or more ratings.

You can grab all articles too in your query, with number of ratings :

```
return Article::where('private', 0)
         ->withCount('ratings')
         ...
```

And you can use a simple condition in your loop to show ratings only for Articles with 5 or more ratings :

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
     @if ($article->count_ratings >= 5)
          // show rating 
     @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You're correct, it's a hasMany relation. Do you have any idea what the standard procedure is with the other articles in this case that have less than 5 votes? They won't show up at all in this case.

Comment: Yes correct, you should use raw query I think and a subquery to get AVG ratings with conditions. Or, grab all articles, and test the count in your loop.